# Flite TTS Sample Rate

Tags: text-to-speech, sample-rate, flite

Is it possible to change the sample rate of the audio output in flite tts? The default output is 16 kHz PCM and I'd like to change it to output 8 kHz.

Comment: Hey and welcome, which programming language are you using? There are many Text-To-Speech provider

Comment: This is using the flite TTS engine in C.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that will do this:

void cst_wave_resample(cst_wave *w, int sample_rate);